# How to handling mouse events on a windows server disconnected user

Tags: c#, windows, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, interrupt-handling

I made a robot application which is moving and clicking mouse in another application.
I want to run this robot in a user which is opening in remote desktop but when I minimize remote desktop or close it robot can not change the mouse position or click it.
Please learn me a solution?

Comment: Is the robot running on your client machine, i.e. the one establishing the connection to the remote machine, or is it running on the remote machine?

Comment: I want to run it on a remote machin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This registry key setting which will send the GUI output anyways:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized`

```
REG_DWORD

1 = Suppress when minimized

2 = Do not suppress when minimized
```

Answer (score 0):

Below mentioned is the complete Resolution Steps with Alternate Option :

**Resolution:**

1. On the remote computer, create a batch file with this code for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do ( %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console)
2. Create a desktop shortcut to this file. To do this, right-click the batch file and select Send to | Desktop (create shortcut).
3. When you need to disconnect from Remote Desktop, run the batch file with admin rights.

**Alternate Resolution:**

1. There needs to be done some registry changes:
2. Launch the Registry editor (regedit.exe)
3. Navigate to one of the following Registry keys, depending on whether you wish to modify the Remote Desktop settings only for the current user or for all users on the computer:
4. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client
5. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client
6. Create a DWORD value named **RemoteDesktop_SuppressWhenMinimized** and set it to **2** (hexadecimal or decimal)
7. Through task manager rdpclip.exe has to be stopped.
8. Disconnect the RDP session by running the following command: tscon %sessionname% /dest:console